# with 'the' or not: 'in areas of' VS 'in the areas of'

Tags: definite-article

1. This will require new frameworks for global cooperation in areas of investment, research and technology.
2. This will require new frameworks for global cooperation in the areas of investment, research and technology.

Answer (score 1):

(First, "this" is vague; even with context, the reader may not know whether "this" refers to a specific noun in an earlier sentence or a condition described in an earlier sentence, paragraph, or section.)

The sentences have slightly different meanings. Since "areas of investment, research and technology" doesn't include the definite article "the", it could be interpreted to mean various facets *within* the fields of investment, research, and technology. Perhaps it refers to investment *into emerging markets*, *corporate* research, and *military* technology, for example. This meaning could be emphasized by adding a few clarifying words:

> This [expansion/objective/modification] will require new frameworks for global cooperation in [certain] areas [within the fields] of investment, research and technology.

In contrast, the definite article "the" in "the areas of investment, research and technology" simply refers exactly to those stated general fields, all of which will require new frameworks for global cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

The second sounds much more natural to me.

I cannot give you a specific rule for this, but the following general observations may be useful.  It seems to me that when '**in areas of**' is followed by a single category you do not need to use the definite article, e,g,:

> **In areas of** extreme poverty you will often find...
>
> I will be **in areas of** the state where there has been drought.
>
> Be careful if you are touring **in areas of** conflict.

If '**in areas of**' is followed by more than one categories, then the definite article is required, e.g.:

> He is an expert **in the areas of** health, psychology and administration.
>
> They conduct business **in the areas of** waste management, recycling and treatment of industrial waste.

You can also use the expression '**in the area of**' when it is only followed by a single category, e.g.:

> He is an expert **in the area of** health.
>
> I would like to work **in the area of** Public Relations.

The phrase '**in the area of**' is also used to indicate an approximate location or amount, e.g.:

> Your salary will be **in the area of** $120,000 annually.
>
> I have pain the **in the area of** my kidneys.
>
> All people **in the area** of Sacramento are encouraged to participate.